Flipping (inverts) Y axis in a Codename One
Here's the code that inverts the y axis to draw from bottom to top (rather than top to bottom as usual).
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class InvertedYAxisSquare extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Inverted Y-Axis Square");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new InvertedYAxisSquare());
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.scale(1, -1);
        at.translate(0, -getHeight());
        g2d.transform(at);
        g2d.fillRect(50, 0, 100, 111);
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}

Please provide similar code using transform and the codename one library.
My attempts were not successful, e.g. this:
---------
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    int height = getHeight();
    Transform t = Transform.makeIdentity();
    t.scale(1, -1);
    t.translate(0, -height);
    g.setTransform(t);
    g.setColor(0x0000ff);
    g.fillRect(50, 0, 100, 100);
    g.resetAffine();
}
--------


The square is somewhere higher than in the middle, and not at the very bottom, as it should be.

That is odd. I'll ask Steve about it as he dealt with the affine work.

@ShaiAlmog
Please suggest any option on how to achieve normal inversion along the y axis. Maybe you have a demo project somewhere or something like that.

Something like this is what you want:
final Form f = new Form(new BorderLayout());
        Component custom = new Component() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                int height = getHeight();
                Transform t = Transform.makeIdentity();
                t.translate(getAbsoluteX(), height + getAbsoluteY());
                t.scale(1, -1);
                t.translate(-getAbsoluteX(), -getAbsoluteY());
                g.setTransform(t);
                g.setColor(0x0000ff);
                g.fillRect(50, 0, 100, 111);
                g.resetAffine();
            }
        };
        f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, custom);
        f.show();

Modified this answer after I saw that there was a problem with the original answer.
The key is to first translate the component to the screen origin.  Then scale it.  Then translate it back.
